# clocking MSP430 UART from DCO

Tags: microcontroller, serial, uart, msp430

I'm designing a simple remote-controlled sensor.
It's going to be connected with others and a master device using RS485.
All it's going to be doing is transmitting the status of a few digital lines and controlling a few relays and LEDs.

I've used MSP430's for some other projects, so decided to use the cheapest MSP430 with a hardware UART I could find.
This turned out to be the MSP430G2203.

After reading the MSP430x2xx user guide I realized that for clocking the UART I have 2 options: the DCO and the low frequency oscillator.
From the datasheet of the MSP430G2203 I got that even the calibrated DCO frequency is -6% ... +6% in the entire temperature range. To me this doesn't seem to be a good-enough clock source for a UART.
From the datasheet I also got that the low frequency oscillator is designed to work with 32768Hz crystals.

So, I have the following questions:

1) Has anyone tried clocking the MSP430 UART from the DCO? Were there any problems? Or should I use autobaud to compensate the clock frequency drift?

2) Has anyone tried clocking the UART from the low frequency oscillator?
What crystal frequencies does the low-frequency oscillator actually support, maybe there are more UART-friendly frequencies available?

Comment: I don't really think you can do more than a low speed (under 9600 bps) using the DCO (I had this problem recently, if I went faster than 9600bps I started getting lots of errors) or the LF oscillator.

Comment: Please re-post this question on **Embedded System** SE site.